# Trying to receive DropDownList input as a string for use in a POST method

Tags: c#

I'm editing the login made by MVC 5's Individual User Accounts option on Account Authentication to add a DropDownList that contains the roles I've seeded into the AspNetRoles table in my database.

The problem is that I'm unsure of how to obtain the name of the role from the DropDownList as string data so I can pass it into my POST method so I can then pass the string data into a UserManager.AddToRoleAsync method to add the role to the user being created. The drop down list displays the 2 roles currently in the system.

Whenever I run the POST method, The ModelState isnt valid, fails and when I check the attempted values, for RoleName is comes up as 1, which is correct but the error I get is:

> {"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type >'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole' failed because no type >converter can convert between these types."}

So I'm not too sure how to fix it, but it appears as if its trying to convert the string 1 value from me selecting Admin from the DropDownList into an IdentityRole.

Thanks in advance.

AccountController GET StaffRegister:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult StaffRegister()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
            var viewModel = new StaffRegisterViewModel
            {
                RoleName = roles
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

AccountController POST StaffRegister:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> StaffRegister(StaffRegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new Staff { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                string selectedRole = model.RoleName.ToString();
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id,selectedRole);
```

StaffRegisterViewModel:

```
public class StaffRegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<IdentityRole> RoleName { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Staff { get; set; }
    }
```

StaffRegister View:

```
@model BigVisionGames.Models.StaffRegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Staff Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("StaffRegister", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.RoleName, new SelectList(Model.RoleName, "Id", "Name"), "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model you should have both List and property to hold collection and item selected. update your model with below code

```
public class StaffRegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleNames { get; set; }

        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser Staff { get; set; }
    }
```

your get method

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult StaffRegister()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
            var rolesSelctedListItems= new List<SelectListItem>();


     foreach(var item in roles)   {
              rolesSelctedListItems.Add(new SelectListItem  {
                   Text = item.Name,
                   Value = item.Id,           
                     });
               }

            var viewModel = new StaffRegisterViewModel
            {
                RoleNames =  rolesSelctedListItems
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Update your view where your minding RoleNames with below code

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.RoleName, Model.RoleNames, "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I get this error when I load the view: **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.** and its comes from the DropDownListFor in the View. The IEnumerable<SelectListItem> is underlined green with message **Suspicious cast: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole and Sys.Coll.Generic.IEnum<Sys.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>**

Comment: VS is telling me that "roles" does not contain a definition for ToSelectListItem

Comment: I have referenced System.Web.Mvc, but the error is still there

Comment: "'SelectListItem' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments" and "cannot convert source type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' " are the errors i'm getting.

Comment: @LTzarz it seems you didnt construct selectlistitem. i included that code as well. use my updated answer

Comment: var rolesSelectedListItems = new SelectList - "'SelectList' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" and "'SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'SelectList' could be found" and "Cannot resolve symbol 'Add'"

Comment: I got as far as being able to submit the form but I got the error "Role 1 does not exist" at await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id,selectedRole); in my StaffRegister POST method

Comment: may be that is different error..not related to dropdown list

Comment: Seems like it, but your solution seemed to have worked

Comment: when you debugged..what is the value of selectedRole you are getting

Comment: It was 1, but I set up an if statement so if the value of selected role was 1 then I'd set the value of the roleNameToAddToUser variable I made to "Admin", and if it was 2 then it'd be Store Foreman and that worked, my system only requires about 2-3 staff roles so this'll do nicely. Thanks so much for your help!